# Mopa can not call post-install-cmd script

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap, composer-php

everyone!

I'm using the MopaBootstrapBundle in Symfony 2.1. Following the instructions in the documentation, when I call composer update it all goes well until it tries to generate the autoload files. There's a script it's suposed to call and it gives this error message:

```
Class Mopa\BootstrapBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler is not autoloadable, can not call post-install-cmd script
```

The bundle is correctly registered in AppKernel, I think I have to make something with composer to make the class loadable but I don't know what or where. Anyone had this problem?